# Should a random string generation method be static?

Tags: c#, function, class, random, static

I want to make a `function` that puts several `strings` together to form a random name. I also want this `function`to be callable from any `class`. All it does is to assign a name to an `instance`.

Should this be a `static function`, or is it better to make a `name-giver instance` every time you generate a new name, and why is it so?

I want to focus on using as little memory as possible.

Comment: What language are you using?  Better to add the relevant language tag.

Comment: I am currently using C#, but assume this issue can be generalized

Comment: A static method does not use less "memory" than a non-static method.  The only difference is whether it needs _instance_ data.  If it does not, then making is static is perfectly reasonable.  But that's unclear based on "All it does is to assign a name to an instance."

Comment: If one of these strings were the "main" string, or "more important" than the others, I guess I would consider it the main object instance, and I would do an extension method of the class String. Otherwise, a static method would be fine.